# How do I find my .NET Core web app running in Docker?

Tags: docker, .net-core

When I run my .NET Core API locally in VS, I can hit it at `localhost:5000`. I added a Dockerfile to containerize it, but it's not clear to me how to figure out what port to expose and use?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -o /app/published-app
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine as runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/published-app /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "/app/Api.dll" ]
```

The image builds, and I run it with this command:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 --name my-api -d my-api
```

I can see it running on port 5000 in my Docker Client, but navigating to `localhost:5000` yields no results ("localhost didn't send any data").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the ASPNETCORE_URLS and EXPOSE to the runtime image section as shown below also try changing

```
http://*:5000
```

to

```
http://+:5000
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -o /app/published-app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine as runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/published-app /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "/app/Api.dll" ]
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'm still getting the same results. What does changing the `*` to a `+` do?

Comment: I found my issue. I was only checking the swagger page, which only runs in development mode. My app was running in release mode in my docker container, so it wasn't showing up. Once I thought to check an actual endpoint on my API, I realized it was working. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to run it in developement mode you can add this line after **ASPNETCORE_URLS** `ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`

Answer (score 1):

Rakesh's answer works, but I just want to give you another option. I prefer to let the container listen on port 80 as it's the default. If you want to do that, you can remove the EXPOSE and ASPNETCORE_URLS statements, so your Dockerfile becomes

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -o /app/published-app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine as runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/published-app /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "/app/Api.dll" ]
```

Then you need to map port 80 to the port you want, when you run it

```
docker run -p 5000:80 --name my-api -d my-api
```

Now you can reach it on http://localhost:5000/

The reason .NET apps based on the aspnet images listen on port 80 by default is that Microsoft set the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable to `http://+:80` in it and that overrides any port configuration you have in your appsettings.

Comment: This gets me the same results as with Rakesh's answer. I wonder if there's something other than the port numbers that's going on?

Comment: @BrendanMcMahon Maybe. You can check in the log to see what port the application is listening on with `docker logs <container name>`.

Comment: I figured it out. I was only checking the swagger page to see if it was working, but Swagger by default only runs in development mode, while I was running in release mode in my docker container. Turns out it was working after all! Thanks for the help.